# StaticRouter renders a leading slash for <Link> tags [react-router 4.0.0]

Tags: javascript, reactjs, express, react-router, react-router-v4

I'm trying to set up a universal react app with react-router 4.0.0.

Server-side rendering works except for the fact that my Link tags are rendered differently on the server and the client. Here is the error message:

> Warning: React attempted to reuse markup in a container but the checksum was invalid. This generally means that you are using server rendering and the markup generated on the server was not what the client was expecting. React injected new markup to compensate which works but you have lost many of the benefits of server rendering. Instead, figure out why the markup being generated is different on the client or server:
>
> ```
> (client) o Furb</h1><a href="./" data-reactid="4"
> (server) o Furb</h1><a href="/./" data-reactid="4
> ```

I am very new to react-router and react in general, so keep in mind this might be a trivial error in my code. Also, I'm learning as I go along, so, there are probably other clamorous mistakes in my code, sorry in advance.

Looking online I came up with this bug fix that covers a similar problem: https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/pull/4484

However, this patch is included in react-router 4.0.0 (I poked the code and it's indeed fixed). Therefore, my issue cannot be caused by this.

After a lot of tinkering, I suspect my config or an error arising from my limited understanding of what I'm doing. For example, for StaticRouter, I'm using `location={req.originalUrl}` instead of `location={req.url}` as `req.url` always seems to be `/`, and I'm not sure why.

I'm posting the files I believe relevant below, but if you want to check the full code you may find it here: https://github.com/magp/furb/tree/universal

package.json

```
{
  "name": "furb",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "description": "A boilerplate for Firebase-UniversalRedux-Bootstrap/MaterialUI projects",
  "main": "app/server.jsx",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "concurrently --kill-others \"npm run start:api\" \"npm run start:back\"",
    "start:back": "node app/serverlauncher.js",
    "start:api": "node api/server.js",
    "clean": "rimraf static",
    "serve:prod": "http-server ./static -o -p 3032",
    "build:app": "NODE_ENV=production webpack --config config/webpack-prod-config.js",
    "build": "npm run clean && npm run build:app && npm run serve:prod",
    "test": "echo 'NODE_ENV=production mocha './tests/**/*.spec.js' --compilers js:babel-core/register'",
    "lint": "eslint --config=./.eslintrc app/**/**/*.jsx"
  },
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": "git+https://github.com/magp/furb.git"
  },
  "keywords": [
    "Boilerplate",
    "React",
    "Redux",
    "UniversalJS",
    "Bootstrap",
    "MaterialUI"
  ],
  "author": "magp",
  "license": "MIT",
  "bugs": {
    "url": "https://github.com/magp/furb/issues"
  },
  "homepage": "https://github.com/magp/furb#readme",
  "dependencies": {
    "express": "^4.15.2",
    "history": "^4.6.1",
    "react": "^15.4.2",
    "react-dom": "^15.4.2",
    "react-hot-loader": "^3.0.0-beta.6",
    "react-router-dom": "^4.0.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-core": "^6.24.0",
    "babel-loader": "^6.4.0",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.24.0",
    "babel-preset-react": "^6.23.0",
    "concurrently": "^3.4.0",
    "eslint": "^3.17.1",
    "eslint-config-airbnb": "^14.1.0",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.2.0",
    "eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y": "^4.0.0",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "^6.10.0",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "^2.28.0",
    "http-server": "^0.9.0",
    "node-sass": "^4.5.0",
    "rimraf": "^2.6.1",
    "sass-loader": "^6.0.3",
    "style-loader": "^0.14.0",
    "webpack": "^2.2.1",
    "webpack-dev-middleware": "^1.10.1",
    "webpack-hot-middleware": "^2.17.1"
  }
}
```

app/serverlauncher.js

```
require('babel-register')({
  presets: [ 'es2015', 'react' ]
});

var app = require('./server.jsx');
```

app/server.jsx

```
var path = require('path');
var express = require('express');

var React = require('react');
var ReactDOMServer = require('react-dom/server');
var StaticRouter = require('react-router-dom/StaticRouter').default;
var webpack = require('webpack');

var config = require('../config/webpack-dev-config');
var Routes = require('./routes/Routes.jsx').default;

var app = express();
var compiler = webpack(config);

app.use(require('webpack-dev-middleware')(compiler, {
  noInfo: true,
  publicPath: config.output.publicPath
}));

app.use(require('webpack-hot-middleware')(compiler));

const routes = [
    '/',
    '/about'
];

app.use('*', function (req, res, next) {
  const context = {};
  const componentHTML = ReactDOMServer.renderToString(<StaticRouter context={context} location={req.originalUrl}><Routes /></StaticRouter>);

  const HTML = `
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
      <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Static</title>
      </head>
      <body>
        <div id="app">${componentHTML}</div>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="/static/source.js"></script>
      </body>
    </html>
  `;
  res.end(HTML);
});

const PORT = process.env.PORT || 3030;

app.listen(PORT, 'localhost', function(err) {
  if (err) {
    console.log(err);
    return;
  }
  console.log('Listening at http://localhost:3030');
});
```

app/routes/Routes.jsx

```
import React from 'react';
import { Route, Switch } from 'react-router-dom';

import List from '../components/List';
import About from '../components/About';
import NotFound from '../components/NotFound';

import links from '../../api/data/links.json';

const linksarr = Object.keys(links).map(function(k) { return links[k] });

function Routes() {
  return (
    <Switch>
      <Route exact path="/" render={props => (<List links={linksarr} {...props} />)} />
      <Route exact path="/about" component={About} />
      <Route component={NotFound} />
    </Switch>
  );
}

export default Routes;
```

app/components/Layout.jsx

```
import React from 'react';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';

function Layout() {
  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Welcome to Furb</h1>
      <Link to="./">Home</Link>
      <Link to="./about">About</Link>
      <Link to="./test">Test</Link>
    </div>
  );
}

export default Layout;
```

Excuse the long question and thank you in advance for any help you can provide.

Comment: Try dropping the period in the "to" field of your Links. It should be just "/", "/about" etc., not "./about". Routes are NOT file paths, they are parsed and interpreted by the Router, and the periods are confusing it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try dropping the period in the "to" field of your Links. It should be just "/", "/about" etc., not "./about". Routes are NOT file paths, they are parsed and interpreted by the Router, and the periods are confusing it.

```
import React from 'react';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';

function Layout() {
  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Welcome to Furb</h1>
      <Link to="/">Home</Link>
      <Link to="/about">About</Link>
      <Link to="/test">Test</Link>
    </div>
  );
}

export default Layout;
```

Comment: Thanks for your speedy answer! You are absolutely correct. This fixed the issue!